# python - argparse error: unrecognized arguments

Tags: python

I'm trying to pass the contents of an email as an argument and it's failing I need to know how to get it to not fail out and just read it as a giant string so that I can ultimately transform the string and use elsewhere.

script -

```
import sys
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('message', help='message to update the wiki')
args = parser.parse_args()

print args.message
```

My argument is actually an email message so the actual script would be run like this (yes it's a giant string being passed as an argument) -

```
update_wiki.py <html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=us-ascii"><meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 12 (filtered medium)"><style></style></head><body lang=EN-CA link=blue vlink=purple><div class=WordSection1><p class=MsoNormal>Hello There!<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>This is an update to the daily log!<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif"'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif"'>________________________________________________<br><br><b>Name Name<br></b>Title | Dept<br><b>COMPANY<br></b>Address | North Pole, CAN | H0H 0H0<br>T: +1 (555) 123-4567<br><a href="mailto:blah@blah.com" target="_blank">blah@blah.com</a> | <a href="http://www.blah.com/" target="_blank">www.blah.com</a><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p></div></body></html>
```

edit - same error persists even if quoting the argument as " " or """ """

Comment: *"it's a giant string being passed as an argument"* - then put it in quotes.

Comment: same error comes with the quotes.  specifically """ """

Comment: Why not pass the message on standard input instead of the command line?

Comment: You need to quote the argument in the shell; this isn't a Python issue: `update_wiki.py '<html xmlns:v="urn:...'`.

Comment: @jwodder that and an intake file would be fine.

Comment: If you feel the need to add a disclaimer to your question like "yes it's a < ridiculous thing >" then maybe that should indicate to you that < ridiculous thing > may not be the best approach. Passing large things like this on the command line successfully can get complicated because you need to handle a large number of escapes and possibly special characters, especially coming from a source like an e-mail. Consider piping it through stdin as jwodder suggested, or writing it to a temp file and just passing the file name instead.

Comment: @pkrrgwasme - unfortunately I'm dealing with the constraints of other applications.  If there was another way I would definitely entertain it but as of now I can think of no other way.  If I knew a way to save this value as a string or an stdin I would but as of now it can only be passed as a raw string that I have to figure out how to consume and get "into" my code.